# Finding an item in a circular queue?

Tags: queue

I have a circular queue of ordered items. I want to know if an item with the value of "x" is in it.

What is the best way (algorithm) to do this?

Comment: More info, please. What language/library?

Comment: not specific to any lang, but a general queue searching problem.

Comment: dumb question: can you access any element of the queue in constant time (like an array) or is it more like a linked list where you have to step through each element?

Comment: You're getting vague answers because you asked a vague question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access each item by index, you can use a binary search.

If you can only see the first item, you need to pop them from the queue until the search key is lower than the key of the item you just popped. Since the queue is sorted, you can stop as soon as you know that the key can't be in the queue anymore.

[EDIT] Since you can access by index: Warp the circular queue in an object which maps it to an "array" (i.e. with a method `get(index)` where `index` runs from `0` to `length-1` and which internally does `((index+start)%length)`.

That way, you can apply the binary search without thinking about the actual data layout.

Comment: A circular queue *does* allow access via index (since it's a simple array) but the start and the end of the queue rotate which makes binary search more difficult (not impossible). The sort of situations where you use circular queues usually makes binary searches unnecessary (they're usually reasonably small).

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is a subjective term and circular queues are rarely large enough to warrant binary searches so I'd opt for simplicity in the absence of information regarding queue size. The easiest way is just to start at the head and check each element until the tail (or you've passed beyond it in the order) to see if it exists.

Let's say your head variable points to the first item that will be removed and the tail points to the next place to put an item. Further assume that you're wasting an item slot to simplify the code (a trick to simplify the code and tell the difference between an empty and full queue). That means and empty queue is indicated by `tail == head`.

```
ptr = head
while ptr != tail:
    if element[ptr] = searchvalue:
        return true
    if element[ptr] > searchvalue:
        return false
    ptr = (ptr + 1) % queuesize;
return false
```

Comment: He said "ordered items", so perhaps a binary search is possible?

Comment: What is the difference between a Circular Queue and a LIFO?

Comment: @Anthony, a LIFO is any structure that does last-in-first-out of which a unidirectional circular queue is one type.

Answer (score 0):

can we traverse in the opposite direction? ie from tail to head. if so then we can design something that can utilize it. ie decide which way to proceed the search.

Since it is ordered we can guess about its position (just a guess or perhaps utilize statistics if available) and then start the full search only in direction which would get the result in less pulls

Answer (score 0):

The OP I suspect, has a fixed sized circular buffer. Two search conditions occur.

One while the buffer is filling and one when the buffer is filled where wrap around has occurred and there is over writing of previous stores.

The first case is a linear search with the start 'slot' at zero and the end slot is presumably recorded/maintained.

The second case is trickier. The start slot circulates as previous stores are over written. The end slot also circulates, just one position following the start slot.

To do a linear search over these moving indexes a translation is needed to place the start slot at zero and the end slot at the buffer size.

How that algorithm works is yet to be determined.